# How to remove all elements found in GROUP B to GROUP A in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's say I have two groups defined in  my Lua script

```
groupA = {"donkey", "goat", "eagle", "whale", "dolphine", "dog", "mosquito", ...}
groupB = {"goat", "mosquito", "donkey"}
```

After the remove operation, the value of groupA have no more elements: "goat", "mosquito", and "donkey"

How do I remove all items in `groupA` that are found in `groupB`. I know we can loop through the items and compare each one but I prefer any API or simple built in statements that solve this types of problem. The elements could also be any type like record.

Comment: "elements could also be any type like record": sounds like you want a "deep" comparison. For that, you could research "deep copy" in Lua.

Comment: @TomBlodget I  understand what you meant. My intention is to filter the objects based on object.Id().  All objects with matching Id in the other set will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of researching, I found out that this simple subtraction in Lua works for groups (or table) to remove elements found in a group from another.

Ex.

```
groupA = groupA - groupB
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in operators that calculate set difference in Lua. You can do what you described and to speed up this process you can build a hash of elements from the second table and then iterate over the elements in the first table and check if they are present in the hash (of the elements in the second table).

If you end up using `table.remove` to remove elements from the first table while iterating, you need to be careful to iterate from the end, otherwise you may end up skipping elements you need to remove.

You can also check if some of the suggestions [in this thread about set operators](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00646.html) work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
local lookup = {}
for i, v in ipairs(groupB) do
  lookup[v] = true
end

local answer = {}
for i, v in ipairs(groupA) do
  if (not lookup[v]) then
    table.insert(answer, v)
  end
end
```

- create a lookup table for the unique items in `groupB`
- traverse `groupA` and lookup each item in the lookup table
- add items from `groupA` *not* found in the lookup table to `answer` table

Note: this approach doesn't account for duplicates. For example, if `groupB` contains `"goat"` three times, and `groupA` contains `"goat"` four times, then `answer` will contain `"goat"` zero times.

Comment: Accepted this answer since its fast and i think its the simplest way to implement the solution.